# $ABC$ is a triangle and $A =(2,3,5)$ , $B=(-1,3,2)$ and $C=(\lambda , 5, \mu)$ If .....

Tags: vector-spaces

Problem :

$ABC$ is a triangle and $A =(2,3,5)$, $B=(-1,3,2)$, and $C=(\lambda , 5, \mu)$. If the median through $A$ is equally inclined to the axes, then find the the value of $\lambda, $ and $\mu$.

My approach :

Midpoint of $BC$ is $(\frac{\lambda -1}{2} ,4, \frac{2+ \mu }{2})$

Direction ratios of the median through $A$ are $\frac{\lambda -1}{2}-2,4 -3$ and $\frac{2+\mu }{2}-5$ ie. $\frac{\lambda -5}{2}, 1 $ and $\frac{\mu -8}{2}$

Now further I won't understand and when I refer the solution it was written :

The median is equally inclined to the axes, so the direction ratios must be equal ie.  $\frac{\lambda -5}{2} = 1 = \frac{\mu -8}{2}$ .. ( please guide me about this statement as I am unable to understand why so ? )

Will be of great help to me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Equally inclined means the angle from the vector to the axes are equal, which means the tangents of those angles are equal and your direction ratios are just those tangents.